# R: Put me through on the accuracy function on forecast package for time series

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

I intend to find Root Mean Squared Error for an `ARIMA` forecast method which I simulated its data. My method is done as follows using `R` as I followed [Rob J. Hyndman](https://otexts.com/fpp2/) approach:

1. Divide the time series data into `train` and `test` sets.
2. Obtain the best model through `auto.arima()` function
3. Forecast for the train data set into the future up to the length of the test set.
4. Calculate the `RMSE` of the forecast.

**MWE**

```
library(forecast)
n=50
phi <- 0.6
set.seed(106100125)
ar1 <- arima.sim(n, model = list(ar=phi, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)

train <- head(ar1, round(length(ar1) * 0.8)) # Train set

test <- tail(ar1, length(ar1) - length(train)) # Test set

nfuture <- forecast(train, model = auto.arima(train), h = length(test))      # makes the `forecast of test set to the future up to length of test set

RMSE <- accuracy(test, nfuture)      # RETURN RMSE
```

When I call `RMSE` as I use it in **MWE** I got `0`. But when I called `test` and `nfuture` I got

```
#[1]  1.0470537  0.3984545  0.5811056  2.2703350 -1.0060028 -1.6126040 -0.4329466  2.1523534  1.2588265  0.7308986
```

and

```
#[1] 0.55281252 0.42374990 0.32481894 0.24898494 0.19085556 0.14629738 0.11214200 0.08596072 0.06589186 0.05050839
```

respectively which show both are not similar thus, `RMSE` can not be `0`

Please help me out on what I have done wrong and put me through on what I need to do to make it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your code, the following error is produced:

```r
RMSE <- accuracy(test, nfuture)
#> Error in xx - ff[1:n]: non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

You have switched the order of the arguments. If you fix that problem, you get the following result

```r
accuracy(nfuture, test)
#>                     ME      RMSE       MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE
#> Training set 0.1068326 0.7035255 0.5543322 146.47245 194.2587 0.9426693
#> Test set     0.3185452 1.2399912 1.0237739  81.17983  82.4495 1.7409780
#>                   ACF1 Theil's U
#> Training set 0.1696878        NA
#> Test set     0.1777069 0.9050431
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>